# Vuetify autocomplete appears blank until focussed

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

When I try and select a value for a `<v-autocomplete>` field programmatically, the field appears blank until I click/focus on it. Then the correct value shows and is already selected.

```
        <v-autocomplete
            :placeholder="placeholder"
            v-model="selected"
            item-value="id"
            item-text="name"
            :items="items"
            menu-props="{'closeOnClick' : true, 'closeOnContentClick: true'}"
            chips
            deletable-chips
            small-chips
            multiple
            ref="input"
        />
```

**computed**

```
  computed: {

//
      selected: {
          get() {
              return this.value;
          },
          set(val) {
              return this.value = val;
          }
      },
```

and I set the selected value with (eg):

```
this.$refs.input.selcted = 5;
```

once I click on it, I will see that Item 5 was indeed selected and will show properly after focus.

Answer (score 1):

Since the value is updated on input event, you could trigger this event whenever you want to update bound model.

```
this.$refs.input.$emit('input', 5)
```

Comment: there is no change with this. any other ideas?